# C++ Template with parameter of a specific type

Tags: c++

How can I have more than one template parameter? Why does this not work?

```
template <class T, int size>
class List {
public:
    void addElement(int);
private:
    T arr[size];
};

template <class T, int size>
void List<T,int>::addElement(T n){
    arr[0] = n;
}

int main(){
    List<int,5> l;
    l.addElement(3); //example method
}
```

Error message:

```
main.cpp:10:16: error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template
parameter list for 'template<class T, int size> class List'  void
List<T,int>::addElement(T n){
                ^ main.cpp:10:16: note:   expected a constant of type 'int', got 'int' main.cpp: In function 'void addElement(T)':
main.cpp:11:5: error: 'arr' was not declared in this scope
     arr[0] = n;
     ^~~
```

Fromo http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4bf130e4d6ed4342

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "not work". There isn't enough information here to identify or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is your code actually outside of any functions? Is the class actually missing a semicolon? It's hard to work with code that isn't a [mcve].

Comment: That's the right syntax to use, so I'm guessing the error is somewhere else. Can you post a minimal self-contained example (one that produces the exact error you're getting when you compile it?)

Comment: I want to define the size of a list on compile time

Comment: @binaryBigInt I cannot reproduce your problem. This code compiles: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76051312ee4d4943

Comment: @binaryBigInt by the way, search for `std::array`.

Comment: Voting to re-open but strongly recommend that you edit the question again to add in your compiler and version and paste in the exact text of the error message you receive.

Comment: You have a typo.  `void List<T,int>::addElement(T n)` should be `void List<T, size>::addElement(int n)` to match how it was declared

Comment: As the error says, `int` is not an integer value; it's a type.

Answer (score 0):

I found some errors in the code.
Let me show you the fixes.

```
template <class T, int size>
class List {
public:
    void addElement(T); //ERROR here is T instead int
private:
    T arr[size];
};

template <class T, int size>
void List<T,size>::addElement(T n){ //ERROR here is <T,size> instead <T,int>
    arr[0] = n;
}

int main(){
    List<int,5> l;
    l.addElement(3);
}
```

I hope I've helped